# How can I loop values of an object array with using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have two arrays like this

```
var v1 = ["1","2","3","4","5"],
    v2 = ["val1","val2","val3","val4","val5"]
```

I want to match values and create html string as;

```
<div data-id="1">val1</div>
<div data-id="2">val3</div>
<div data-id="3">val3</div>
<div data-id="4">val4</div>
<div data-id="5">val5</div>
```

How can I do this with using jquery?

Comment: What do you mean *I want to math values* ?? Or is it *match*? Either way it isn't clear as to what you are looking for.

Comment: are they 2 arrays, or an array of arrays

Comment: What do you mean by `math values`? This is just straightforward DOM insertion in a loop.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SHSuf/1/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a html string use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var a1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
var a2 = ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5"]

var html = $.map(a1, function (val, i) {
    return '<div data-id="' + val + '">' + a2[i] + '</div>'
}).join('');

console.log(html)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/SHSuf/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var ids = ["1","2","3","4","5"]
var values = ["val1","val2","val3","val4","val5"]

$.each(ids, function( index, value ) {
  $('body').append($('<div data-id="' + value + '">' + values[index] + '</div>'));
});
```